# Passing commands as environment-arguments

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to realize two versions of an environment `numberedlist`:

- if **no argument** is passed to it, it should begin the environment `enumerate` and pass **default values** as its argument,
- if **one argument** (or a list of) is passed to it, it should begin the environment `enumerate` and pass **default values + the passed argument** as its argument.

My MWE doesn't work properly. It prints out the arguments instead of using them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{numberedlist}[1][]{%
\let\tempstring{topsep=0.3cm,noitemsep,itemindent=0.5cm,labelsep=0.5cm}%default value
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{%
    \let\tempstring{\tempstring{}#1}%add further params
}%
\begin{enumerate}[\tempstring]%
}{\end{enumerate}}


\begin{document}

\begin{numberedlist}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{numberedlist}

\begin{numberedlist}[resume]
\item continue the list with 4th item!
\item item 5
\item item 6
\end {numberedlist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand the list of default options before `\begin{enumerate}` sees it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\numberedlistdefault{%
  topsep=0.3cm,noitemsep,itemindent=0.5cm,labelsep=0.5cm% default value
}

\newenvironment{numberedlist}[1][]
 {\expandafter\enumerate\expandafter[\numberedlistdefault,#1]}
 {\endenumerate}


\begin{document}

\begin{numberedlist}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{numberedlist}

\begin{numberedlist}[resume]
\item continue the list with 4th item!
\item item 5
\item item 6
\end {numberedlist}

\end{document}
```

But it's perhaps simpler not having a macro:

```
\newenvironment{numberedlist}[1][]
 {\enumerate[
    topsep=0.3cm,
    noitemsep,
    itemindent=0.5cm,
    labelsep=0.5cm,
    #1
  ]}
 {\endenumerate}
```

You don't need a conditional, because `enumitem` happily accepts empty options.

[image]

Comment: Thx egreg, you're soo fast :) Solution 1 works and is the explanation I was looking for. The simpler solution 2 doesn't work. It starts counting from 1 again.

Comment: @musicman Fixed.