# Passing command as argument to `\DefineArrayVar` from `forarray`

Tags: macros

I need to pass `1,2,3,...,\Num` to the `variable list` argument of the `\DefineArrayVar` command from the [`forarray` package](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/forarray/forarray.pdf#page=8). If I pass it manually, everything works fine, but, when I pass a command instead, `\DefineArrayVar` gets confused and fails.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand{\Num}{4}

\newcounter{ct}
\setcounter{ct}{1}

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<\Num}{\thect,}\thect%
}

\DefineArrayVar{ArrayName}{@}
{,}{1,2,3,4} % <---- This works 
% {,}{\test} % <---- This doesn't work
% {,}{\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < \Num}{\thect,}\thect} % <---- This doesn't work either
{,}{4cm,0.8cm,0.6cm,1.6cm}

% This doesn't work
% \expandafter\DefineArrayVar\expandafter{ArrayName}{@}{,}{\test}{,}{4cm,0.8cm,0.6cm,1.6cm}

\DefineArrayDefault{,}{@}{2}{2}{ArrayName}

\begin{document}

\test % To see what 'forloop' is generating

\ArrayName % Proof that it's working (must print "0.8cm")

\end{document}
```

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177018/142706) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411064/142706) (which are very much related to my problem), I also tried to use (separately) `\expandafter` or `\edef` like so:

```
    \expandafter\DefineArrayVar\expandafter{ArrayName}{@}{,}{\test}{,}{4cm,0.8cm,0.6cm,1.6cm}
```

```
    \edef\test{\unexpanded\expandafter{\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct}<\Num}{\thect,}\thect}}
```

but it didn't work.

Well, since I do not understand big picture of what I am doing, I can't go further. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider a different package to store and recall arrays?

`listofitems` supports array constructs and is nice because its array storage technique is fully expandable (that is to say, once read, the recall of array elements is fully expandable).

It also supports multi-dimensional arrays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\ArrayName{4cm,0.8cm,0.6cm,1.6cm}

ArrayName[2] is \ArrayName[2]

The array has \listlen\ArrayName[] elements.

The whole array is \foreachitem\z\in\ArrayName[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else,\fi\z}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much easier, thanks!!! I will try to modify my whole document to test it beyond my MWE. I'm still curious about how would I pass a command to `\DefineArrayVar`'s argument though :)

Comment: @Leone  Thanks.  I'll also give your original problem some thought.

Answer (score 1):

The `forloop` and `forarray` packages are really outdated. With `expl3` you get much more with enhanced flexibility.

Your needs can be fulfilled with “one-liners”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = items
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_leone_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn  { l_leone_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlistitem}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = number of item to retrieve
  \clist_item:cn  { l_leone_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlistlen}{m}
 {% #1 = list name
  \clist_count:c  { l_leone_list_#1_clist }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{ArrayName}{4cm,0.8cm,0.6cm,1.6cm}

\begin{document}

\getlistitem{ArrayName}{4}

X\makebox[\getlistitem{ArrayName}{4}][s]{a\hfil a}X

X\hspace*{1.6cm}X

\end{document}
```

The last example shows that you can use `\getlistitem` in any situation where a length is needed, since the list contains lengths.

[image]

Comment: Good one too! I actually got close when found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513967/142706) of yours, but I didn't know much about `expl3` to get things working, because I need to access data with a counter, which I can do now with this answer, thanks! Just an observation: I had to put `\usepackage{xparse}` in preamble, did you forget it?

Comment: Also, to know that a package is outdated do you see CTAN's timeline? Or is there a place where I can find this information and avoid the old packages? I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/142706), but could find neither `forloop` nor `forarray` on its answers.

Comment: @Leone Outdated is an opinion of mine, but you can see that they’ve been unmaintained for a long time. If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, `xparse` is not needed.